# How to count occurrences of different sets

Tags: r, set

sample code:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
dt <- data.table(id = LETTERS[1:20],
             setvalues = replicate(20,
                sample(letters[1:4], sample(c(2,3),1))))[order(id)]
```

dt

`id setvalues
 1:  A     d,a,b
 2:  B     c,d,a
 3:  C     c,b,d
 4:  D     b,d,c
 5:  E     a,b,c
 6:  F     a,c,b
 7:  G       c,b
 8:  H     b,c,d
 9:  I     b,c,a
10:  J     a,d,b
11:  K     b,d,a
12:  L     b,c,d
13:  M     d,b,a
14:  N       b,c
15:  O       c,d
16:  P       b,d
17:  Q     d,c,b
18:  R     a,d,b
19:  S     a,d,c
20:  T       b,a`

How can count the occurence of each set (order doesn't matter).

The desired results are something like

`setvalue  counts
b,c,d     6
a,b,d     4
a,c,c     3
a,c,d     2
b,c       2
c,d       1
b,d       1
a,b       1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'setvalues' is a `list` of `vector`.  We loop through the `list` with `lapply`, `sort` it, `paste`, use it in the `by` argument and get the 'counts' with `.N`

```
dt[ , .(counts = .N), .(setvalue = unlist(lapply(setvalues, function(x) toString(sort(x)))))]
```

Comment: That is beautifull. I was looking for a specific "set" function - but sorting works just as fine :-)